# How Eureka Server and Spring Cloud API Gateway communicates with each other?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

In **Spring Boot Microservices architecture**, we generally register our each microservice (its many instances) into Eureka server by doing `eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true`, `eureka.client.fetch-registry=true` and  `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka`. So Eureka acts as service registry for these services (service-name, hostname and its IP).

Spring Cloud API Gateway acts as a single point of entry for any microservice call. It can work as a proxy service to route a request to the concerned microservice, abstracting the producer details. It has route information only, then **how Spring Cloud API gateway comes to know which microservice instance to call to? How API Gateway and Eureka communicates and load balance?**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      routes:
      - id: user-service
        uri: lb://user-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/users/**
        
      - id: order-service
        uri: lb://department-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/departments/**
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
```

With the Discovery Locator enabled in API Gateway, you do not have to manually configure the routes unless absolutely needed.

The way API Gateway knows which Eureka Service to route the incoming request to is as follows:

Assuming,
Orders Service runs on http://localhost:8080
API Gateway runs on http://localhost:8082
Eureka Service name for Orders Service - order-service

Then if order-service getOrders endpoint: http://localhost:8080/orders, then with Discovery Locator enabled the request needs to be routed through the API gateway with the following URL: https://localhost:8082/order-service/orders, i.e., **{ApiGatewayHost}/{EurekaServiceId}/{ActualEndpoint}**.

Answer (score 0):

Register Gatway to Eureka Server